# PHP str_replace numbers with other numbers

Tags: php, string

My string of numbers are not replacing correctly.

I am expecting the output after replacing to be `9876543210` but it doesnt seem to be the case.

What am i doing wrong?

```
<?php
$numbers = array('0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9');
$code = array('9', '8', '7', '6', '5', '4', '3', '2', '1', '0');

$pre = '0123456789';
echo $pre . " ==> " . str_replace($numbers, $code, $pre);
?>
```

Comment: Why don't you use `strrev()` ?

Comment: what is your output instead?

Comment: @HamZa : that's just a simple example I am thinking of jumbling the code in another order.

@STTLCU : my output is `0123443210`

Comment: The problem is in the fact that the replace goes in the array order, that meaning that from 0 to 4 (at the beginning), the chars are replaced twice. Take a look at this example @ php.net http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php#example-4820

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That produces the output `0123443210` because str_replace with an array will start replacing earlier matches as it iterates over `$numbers`

For a single letter transposition like this, use [strtr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php) instead

```
 $encoded = strtr($pre, "0123456789", "9876543210");
```

Comment: Seems like a good looking replace. I think in this case this would be the more sensitive way of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit long to explain but let me show you what's happening. For each element in the array it's replacing everything from the start from the string. Let's define **N** for `$number` and **C** for `$code` and **R** for `$result`

```
N       C       R
0       9       9123456789
1       8       9823456789
2       7       9873456789
3       6       9876456789
4       5       9876556789
5       4       9876446789
6       3       9873443789
7       2       9823443289
8       1       9123443219
9       0       0123443210
```

Thus you should use the solution provided by Paul using [`strtr()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php)